# How to throw an error with promise all when there are no data returned?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, api, error-handling

I have created a page that loads some data from api and I want to throw an error from the promise all if the api returns no data. How can this be done?

```
export const fruitsColor = async () : Promise => {
  const response = await fetch(`....`);
  if(!response.ok){
     throw new Error('Error happened')
  }
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
};

export const fruitsType = async (): Promise => {
  const response = await fetch(`....`);
  if(!response.ok){
     throw new Error('Error happened')
  }
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
};

export const getFruitsData = async (): Promise => {
  return await Promise.all([
    fruitsColor,
    fruitsType,
  ])
    .then(values => {
      const results: FruitsStoreType = {
         color: values[0],
         type: values[1],
      };
      return results;
    })
    .catch(() => ({
      color: [],
      type: [],
    }));
};
```

Comment: Do you want `Promise.allSettled`?

Comment: @epascarello how can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "*if the api returns no data*"? Do you want to test for empty arrays? Non-array values? Something else?

Comment: Btw, don't use `.then()` when you can use `await`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to pass `Promise.all([fruitsColor(), fruitsType()]`

`Promise.all` expects Promises and you are passing functions' references.

So, try to add the `()` to both the functions.
In this way the `promise.all` will catch the `error`

throw an error there to reach your goal

```
export const fruitsColor = async (): Promise<any> => {
  const response = await fetch(`....`);
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('Error happened');
  }
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
};

export const fruitsType = async (): Promise<any> => {
  const response = await fetch(`....`);
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error('Error happened');
  }
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
};

export const getFruitsData = async (): Promise<any> => {
  return await Promise.all([fruitsColor(), fruitsType()])
    .then((values) => {
      const results: FruitsStoreType = {
        color: values[0],
        type: values[1],
      };
      return results;
    })
    .catch(() => {
      throw new Error('my own error');
    });
};
```